# How long does it take for Drupal to unblock user after 5 failed attempts?

Tags: drupal

I've tried to log in unsuccessfully to Drupal and I get the following error:

> There have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked.

Does anyone know how long the waiting time is for localhost?

Comment: Please avoid cross-posting. Cross-posted on https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/263530

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross posted

Answer (score 2):

Last time I've checked it was 6 hours. If you want to speed things up and unblock the profile manually just go to the database and run: DELETE FROM `flood`;

Comment: Default is to allow 5 failed attempts every 6 hours.

You can verify this at Drupal user core module.

Comment: n.b. `\Drupal::configFactory()->get('user.flood')->get('user_window') / 3600.0` => `6.0` (hours)